# Is this instruction reordering allowed by the JLS or not?

Tags: java, jvm, memory-model, jls

According to the Java Language Specification ([Example 17.4-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)) the following snippet (starting in `A == B == 0`)...

```
Thread 1             Thread 2
--------             --------
r2 = A;              r1 = B;
B = 1;               A = 2;
```

... can result in `r2 == 2` and `r1 == 1`. This is because the result of executing `B = 1;` does not depend on whether or not `r2 = A` has been executed, thus the JVM is free to swap the order of the execution of those two instructions. In other words, the following interleaving is allowed by the spec:

```
Thread 1             Thread 2
--------             --------
B = 1;
                     r1 = B;
                     A = 2;
r2 = A;
```

which clearly results in `r2 == 1` and `r1 == 1`.

### My question:

Suppose we tweak the example a little:

```
Thread 1             Thread 2
--------             --------
r2 = A;              r1 = B;
monitorenter obj     monitorenter obj
monitorexit obj      monitorexit obj
B = 1;               A = 2;
```

where `obj` is a reference shared between the threads.

**Is the reordering of `r2 = A` and `B = 1` still allowed?**

---

The JLS says...

> *However, compilers are allowed to reorder the instructions in either thread, when this does not affect the execution of that thread in isolation.*

...which sort of indicates that the instructions *may* still be swapped. On the other hand, the following statement

> *An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.*

indicates that under certain schedulings we may have a happens-before relation between the statements in the two threads, which presumably disallows instruction reordering.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the monitored code? If I understand you correctly, those monitoring lines could be optimized out anyway, since zero code has zero effect and overlap, at least in theory.

Comment: Well, if they don't affect the semantics, then sure, they can probably be removed. But if they prevent instruction reordering they *do* affect the semantics, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand that first qouted statement: Even if the monitored blocks are executed reordered, the semantics wouldn't change in isolated execution. The second statement says, that the lock ownership transition is seamless. I understand the whole reording stuff as follows: Reordering is bound to semantics only. Interlocking has no bad effect. But instruction reordering causes (even more) undefined behavior when applied to code, which shares variables without any interlocking mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally, it is not allowed. This is known as the "roach motel model"

http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/05/roach-motels-and-java-memory-model.html

Particularly, an action cannot be moved across a synchronization block.

However, formally, JMM does not speak in terms of reordering. In your example, we can only reason that,

1. either the sync block 1 is before the sync block 2 in the total synchronization order, therefore `r2=A` happens-before `A=2`;`r2` must be 0. But there are no constraints between `B=1` and `r1=B`; `r1` can be 0 or 1.
2. or the other way around. `r1` must be 0, `r2` can be 0 or 2.

So the program still contains data race; nontheless, we can reason that `(r1,r2)` can only be (0,0), (1,0), (0,2); it is impossible to be (1,2)